# ModuleNotFoundError in python 3 - django

Tags: python, django

I have below directory structure

```
--sample-django <base directory>
    - scripts <sub directory>
        - run_scripts.py
    - utilities <sub directory>
        - __init__.py
        - methods.py

----------------------------------------------
run_scripts.py

    from utilities.methods import get_name

    def main():
        print(get_name())

    main()
-----------------------------------------------
```

When I run the run_scripts.py, I get the below error

```
 from utilities.methods import get_name
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utilities'
```

I tried to add sys.path and also PYTHONPATH but did not solve my problem. Please help me to resolve this issue.

```
sys.path.append('/Users/projects/sample-django/utilities')
```

Comment: Are you using a `venv`?

Comment: yes. I used virtual environment

Answer (score 0):

Adding the root directory in the `sys.path` resolved the issue.

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```